# Automatically start a home replacement App after downloading

Tags: android, installation, apk

I have a custom home replacement App, that will not be published on the market. I've implemented an autoupdate functionality to be able to update the customer's app. My question is, is it possible to make the App start defaultly after an update? Now if the user makes an update, the new version is downloaded and installed (replaces the old one), but meanwhile android starts it's default home application (probably, because my is yet not accessible) and the user has to click the home button and choose my application. Is there maybe some directive, or configuration? Thank you. Btw. I install the update with following intent:

```
Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:pl.mymeal.orders");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, packageURI);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + ApkName)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.
Think about the security implications.

Comment: What about implementing a broadcast receiver that listens to ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED action and than run the package explicitly?

Comment: @FilipMajernik Try it and tell us how it went.

Comment: I've just tried it, but the broadcastReceiver is not being called. Any  ideas? The onReceive method is pretty simple and should just yield the Uri of the package, but I see nothing in the logs, any thought???

@Override
public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
    Uri data = intent.getData();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Uri - " + data.toString());
}

Comment: It has worked actually, I've forgotten to set the NEW_ACTIVITY flag in the intent. Now the broadcast receiver receives the action about app replacement and starts the app. There is only one minor problem - the app is started before the user has a chance to click on DONE after updating the app, so the last screen after an update stays somewhere in the stack.